# Android and Azure Mobile Services exception: "Error while processing request"

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am creating a mobile application for Android which interfaces with an Azure .NET backend (or at least it should). I can create a service object and get a table just fine with this code (with the proper values inserted, obviously):

```
MobileSerivceClient mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
    "https://myApp.azure-mobile.net/",
    "myAppKey ",
    this
);
MobileServiceTable myMobileServiceTable = mClient.getTable(MyClass.class);
```

The results are non-null and no exceptions are thrown. However, when I try to execute this code:

```
        myTable.insert(item, new TableOperationCallback<MyClass>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(MyClass entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setMessage("Success!");
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

                if(exception == null)
                {
                    dialog.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    builder.setMessage("Exception: " + exception.getMessage());
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                    dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
```

I receive an error from the server. When inspecting the exception returned in the ServiceFilterResponse object, it seems that the error is caused by a 404 - Not Found response, and the exception returned is of type MobileServiceException. But this doesn't make sense to me, since it *seems* as though I've already connected to my mobile service successfully. Is it, for some reason, not connecting to my SQL tables that I've connected with the mobile service? And does anyone know where in the "stack", if you will, this error is occuring? I can't figure out for the life of me what's causing the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've been playing with the azure mobile services SDK here and this might shed some light.  We got error 404 as well in the MobileServiceException but when we print it, we get "Table name xyz does not exist".  Did you create a table named "MyClass" in your database?  Also, make sure you have objects in MyClass that match the databases columns you have for the "MyClass" table.

Hope that helps.

Comment: As I commented on the above answer, I was able to send a POST request via the help page but haven't had any luck. Unfortunately, the error message is just as the title of the question says, so it doesn't give me much help...I've named the classes in the .NET backend and my Android app the same thing and all their attributes are identical as well. The table was created when I sent the request and it created some columns of its own but I think those are generated by the API (eg Version, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, and Deleted)

Comment: One thing that may be important to note is that there isn't an Id field in my .NET version of the class...but I think based on how it looked that it inherited the Id property from its EntityData base class. Not sure if this helps at all

Comment: Can you try using mClient.getTable("MyClass", MyClass.class) instead of mClient.getTable(MyClass.class).  Using the class name explicitly helped in our case (but we were getting a different error so its really a shot in dark for you...)  And yes, the CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, etc are handled automatically.  The indexed ID should also be handled automatically.

Comment: And just to confirm, is the object values entered in the table but you still get an error?  Or the object values are NOT entered in the table at all?

Comment: It worked! I was already using the getTable overload, but the table in Azure is named as "MyClasses" so I thought that's what I would have to use. I actually just changed it back to the single param overload and it works now, awesome! Thanks for your input and for sticking with the thread :-)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you hit your controller using the help page? Note that you can use the help page when hosted in Azure -- just use the master key as the password when prompted in your browser, the username doesn't matter.

Comment: I can't seem to find the help page you're referring to. I'm assuming this is acquired from accessing the URL of the service directly?

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to send a test POST call and it worked fine! Makes me think something is possibly wrong on my android-side code. Can you possibly shed some light on something that might be going wrong with my android code in the way that I'm calling the service or possibly the way that my android class is structured? Thanks!